# Glare shows in compositing window, not in final render

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am trying to do the Blender Guru Neon tutorial, all good EXCEPT I can't figure out the glare node set up. I have mine set up just like his tutorial shows, but in mine the glare only shows as a preview in the compositing window, does not show up in final render. I have attached a picture of the compositing window view and a shot of the render (bottom).

I am a total noob - I must have something set up wrong. Anybody have any ideas?

[image](Someone else asked an almost identical question to mine, but if you read it, he just says he figured it out and didn't give the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the output of the *Glare* node to the image input of the *Composite* node. Otherwise you're just viewing the result of the glare but not applying it to the compositing output.

Comment: THANK YOU! And here's a tip for anyone else - the Glare is added after the entire render is done - so it renders, then the Glare pops on! You will not see the Glare until the entire render is done