# Why the glare node has no effect on the final rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to add a glare node to my render result via compositing nodes:

[image]

However, when I render animation using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>, the glare does not show up.

I know that I have to change to viewer node for the render if I want to save a single frame. How can I apply those node results to the animation as well?

Comment: Plug the glare into the *Composite* node.

Comment: Even better: [Glare shows in compositing window, not in final render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156577/glare-shows-in-compositing-window-not-in-final-render)

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link up the [Glare](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/glare.html) node to your [Composite](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/composite.html) node. The render will only take into account, what the *Composite* node is connected to. From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/composite.html):

> The Composite node is where the actual output from the Compositor is connected to the renderer. This node is updated after each render, but also reflects changes in the node tree (provided at least one finished input node is connected).

The [Viewer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/texture_node/types/output/viewer.html) node is just a convenient way to *preview* the results of a node in the node tree.

Comment: @brockmann: thank you 

Comment: Thank you all! :D